# Powershell command -- To add a attribute if not exist in a particular node of a XML

Tags: string, powershell, replace, find, addition

```
<APPPOOL APPPOOL.NAME="Classic" RuntimeVersion="v2.0" state="Started">
<add name="Classic" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0">
<APPPOOL APPPOOL.NAME="GetServiceDet" RuntimeVersion="v2.0" state="Started">
<add name="GetServiceDet" autoStart="true">
```

- my file has many line begining with word "add name".
- I want to check if these lines have a string "managedRuntimeVersion".
- if not exists, then i need to add managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" to
  that line.

***Expected Result as below***

```
<APPPOOL APPPOOL.NAME="Classic" RuntimeVersion="v2.0" state="Started">
<add name="Classic" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0">
<APPPOOL APPPOOL.NAME="GetServiceDet" RuntimeVersion="v2.0" state="Started">
<add name="GetServiceDet" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0">
```

I have tried with the below script.. but in the result.. it is given only the lines having "add name"

```
$sfile="C:\Users\subash.s\Desktop\backup\pool.xml"
(((gc "$sfile") | Select-String -Pattern "add name" | 
select-string -notmatch "managedRuntimeVersion") -replace '>',' managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0">') | 
Set-Content "$sfile"
```

with the above script. i got below result..

```
<add name="Classic" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0">
<add name="GetServiceDet" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0">
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the lines to go _Above_ and _Below_

Comment: i have edited my question now for more understanding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Pete's sake, the configuration file is XML, not a text file! Edit it *as an XML document*, and you will save a lot of headaches.

There are a few ways to add attributes into such a document. As the XML in the question is a fragment - and of illegal syntax, the sample code uses a bit modified version of the same. Select all `add` nodes that don't have got `managedRuntimeVersion` attribute, create one and add attribute with values to the nodes. Like so,

```
# Dummy data for testing
[xml]$x = @'
<root>
<APPPOOL APPPOOL.NAME="GetServiceDet" RuntimeVersion="v2.0" state="Started">
<add name="GetServiceDet2" autoStart="true"/>
</APPPOOL>
<APPPOOL APPPOOL.NAME="Classic" RuntimeVersion="v2.0" state="Started">
<add name="Classic" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" />
</APPPOOL>
<APPPOOL APPPOOL.NAME="GetServiceDet" RuntimeVersion="v2.0" state="Started">
<add name="GetServiceDet" autoStart="true"/>
</APPPOOL>
</root>
'@

# Select all add elements that don't have managedRuntimeVersion attribute
$nl=$x.SelectNodes('/root/APPPOOL/add[not(@managedRuntimeVersion)]')
# Add attributes to the elements
foreach($n in $nl) { 
  # Create new attribute and assign a value
  $a = $x.CreateAttribute('managedRuntimeVersion')
  $a.Value = 'v2.0'
  [void]$n.Attributes.Append($a) 
}

# Print modified version to console
$x.save([console]::out)

# Output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<root>
  <APPPOOL APPPOOL.NAME="GetServiceDet" RuntimeVersion="v2.0" state="Started">
    <add name="GetServiceDet2" autoStart="true" />
  </APPPOOL>
  <APPPOOL APPPOOL.NAME="Classic" RuntimeVersion="v2.0" state="Started">
    <add name="Classic" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" />
  </APPPOOL>
  <APPPOOL APPPOOL.NAME="GetServiceDet" RuntimeVersion="v2.0" state="Started">
    <add name="GetServiceDet" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" />
  </APPPOOL>
</root>
```

Reading the actual file and saving changes to disk are left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks for your response @vonPryz .. This is working fine. But it is appending the attribute only to the last node of the xml.. can you please assist on the same. i have use the below code.
`$Path = "C:\Users\subash\Desktop\backup\sample.xml"
$x=[xml] (Get-Content $Path)
$nl=$x.SelectNodes('/appcmd/APPPOOL/add[not(@managedRuntimeVersion)]')
$a =$x.CreateAttribute('managedRuntimeVersion')
$a.Value = 'v2.0'
foreach($n in $nl) { [void]$n.Attributes.Append($a) }
$x.save($Path) `

Comment: Thanks a ton.. the edited script is working very much as i expected.